# Traverse list to parent item with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I'm trying to put together a nested list which I can traverse with arrow keys.

I'm a bit stuck at being able to ascend to a `li` which is a parent of the current `li` element.

`.prev('li')` does not seem to do what I want. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfbx9da4/f5W7X/6/) of where I am at.

Using <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd> shows the desired behaviour I am aiming for.

I have tried putting all `li`s into an array and then doing `.index(current)` to progress to the next but couldn't quite get this write and it seems messy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong function to navigate the DOM.  I'd use .parent('li')

Comment: yeah i could do that conditionally if there are no more siblings but i was hoping there was something simpler